# Segmentation fault when creating a vector of objects for solving an ODE using GSL

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdvector, gsl

I need to create a vector of `ODESolver` objects. If I create an `ODESolver` object, everything is fine, however, if I use a vector I get a segmentation fault when the `ODESolver` constructor is called. Why is this the case and how do I solve this problem?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>    
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>

struct ODESystem {};

struct ODESolver {
    ODESolver(ODESystem &ODE_system)
    {
        d_solver_ptr  = gsl_odeiv_step_rkf45;
        d_step_ptr    = gsl_odeiv_step_alloc(d_solver_ptr, d_dim_ODE);
        d_evolve_ptr  = gsl_odeiv_evolve_alloc(d_dim_ODE);
    }

    ~ODESolver()
    {
        gsl_odeiv_step_free(d_step_ptr);
        gsl_odeiv_evolve_free(d_evolve_ptr);
    }

    const gsl_odeiv_step_type *d_solver_ptr;
    gsl_odeiv_step *d_step_ptr;
    gsl_odeiv_evolve *d_evolve_ptr;
    gsl_odeiv_system d_ODE_system;
    const static int d_dim_ODE = 4;
};

struct MyODESystem : public ODESystem {};

int main()
{
    MyODESystem myODE;
    ODESolver mySolver(myODE);                      // WORKS FINE

    std::vector<MyODESystem> myODEVec;
    myODEVec.push_back(MyODESystem());

    std::vector<ODESolver> mySolverVec;
    mySolverVec.push_back(ODESolver(myODEVec[0]));  // SEGMENTATION FAULT: 11

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing `gsl_odeiv_step_alloc` and `gsl_odeiv_step_free` are similar to `malloc` and `free`. In this case it's clear that you have a problem of "double free". In the following code

```
mySolverVec.push_back(ODESolver(myODEVec[0]));
```

you create a temporary `ODESolver` object which allocates some memory and assigns it to the member variables `d_step_ptr` and `d_evolve_ptr`. The the object is copied with the default copy constructor which just does `memcpy` (copies bits) into the vector. The the temporary object is destroyed and the memory is freed. When the vector `mySolverVec` goes out of scope it destroys all objects inside of it. Which tries to free the same memory again and you most likely have a crash!

You should either prohibit copying of your object. In C++11 you could allow only moves and no copies. If you have to stick with the older standard then some reference counting scheme would make sense. Take a look at `boost` library and specifically `boost::shared_ptr`.